# Is there a swift data structure which can contain a rawValue that can be any of its type and can be switchable

Tags: swift, enums

I need some kind of enum which can accept any `StringLiteralType` in which I don't need to create a lot of boilerplate code.

Here's an example of the boilerplate code I have.

```
enum Sample: RawRepresentable {
    case foo
    case bar
    case unknown(String)

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        if let correspondingValue = Key(rawValue: rawValue)?.correspondingValue {
            self = correspondingValue
        } else {
            self = .unknown(rawValue)
        }
    }

    private enum Key: String {
        case foo
        case bar

        var correspondingValue: Sample {
            switch self {
            case .foo: return .foo
            case .bar: return .bar
            }
        }

        init?(withSample sample: Sample) {
            switch sample {
            case .foo: self = .foo
            case .bar: self = .bar
            case .unknown: return nil
            }
        }
    }

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case let .unknown(value): return value
        default: return Key(withSample: self)?.rawValue ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have defined cases (foo, bar, etc) which have default values that I can use to switch against, and then I want to have an `unkown(String)` which can contain any value.

This can be easily done by just using `String` and some kind of `Constants` like this for example.

```
enum Constants {
    static let foo = "foo"
    static let bar = "bar"
}

// sample usage

let someString = "aaaa"

let sample = Sample(rawValue: someString)! // don't mind the implicit unwrapping
switch sample {
case Constants.foo:
    // do something
case Constants.bar:
    // do something
default:
    // do something with unknown someString
}
```

The idea here is to be able to use sample like this.

```
let someString = "aaaa"

let sample = Sample(rawValue: someString)! // don't mind the implicit unwrapping
switch sample {
case .foo:
    // do something
case .bar:
    // do something
case .unknown(let value):
    // do something
}
```

**EDIT:**

Why it needs to be an Enum
- Autocomplete in XCode using enums
- Adding functionality will be easy when adding new cases when using `switch`

Why it needs to be `RawRepresentable`
- This gets stored to persistence via it's `RawValue`.
- I can also use protocols under `ExpressibleByXXXXXXLiteral` by doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I made so far.

I first created an enum which contains two cases with associated values, one is for a sub enum of known entities and the other is for unknown entities.

```
enum Foo {
    case known(Bar)
    case unknown(String)

    enum Bar: String {
        case fiz, baz
    }
}
```

I then extended the said enum to have `RawRepresentable` capabilities

```
extension Foo: RawRepresentable {
    init?(rawValue: String) {
        if let bar = Bar(rawValue: rawValue) {
            self = .known(bar)
        } else {
            self = .unknown(rawValue)
        }
    }

    init(stringValue: String) {
        self.init(rawValue: stringValue)!
    }

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case let .known(bar): return bar.rawValue
        case let .unknown(string): return string
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample usage.

```
let foo: Foo = .known(.fiz)

switch foo {
case .known(.fiz):
    ... do something
case .known(.baz):
    ... do something
case .unknown(let str):
    ... do something
}
```

PS: This could possibly be a nice thing to propose in Swift Evolution, so there would be less boilerplate I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Does it *need* to be `RawRepresentable`? The code below works per your requirement…

```
enum Sample {
    case foo, bar, unknown(StringLiteralType)

    init(_ string: StringLiteralType) {
        switch string {
        case "foo": self = .foo
        case "bar": self = .bar
        default: self = .unknown(string)
        }
    }
}


let sample = Sample("aaa")
switch sample {
case .foo:
    print("foo")
case .bar:
    print("bar")
case .unknown(let value):
    print(value)
}
// aaa
```

---

*Edit*

```
enum Sample: RawRepresentable {
    case foo, bar, unknown(StringLiteralType)
    enum Keys: String {
        case foo, bar
        var sample: Sample {
            switch self {
            case .foo: return .foo
            case .bar: return .bar
            }
        }
    }

    init(rawValue: StringLiteralType) {
        self = Keys(rawValue: rawValue)?.sample ?? .unknown(rawValue)
    }

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .foo: return Keys.foo.rawValue
        case .bar: return Keys.bar.rawValue
        case .unknown(let value): return value
        }
    }
}

print(Sample(rawValue: "aaa").rawValue) // aaa
print(Sample(rawValue: "foo").rawValue) // foo
print(Sample.foo.rawValue) // foo
print(Sample.bar.rawValue) // bar
```

Comment: it needs to be rawRepresentable because this gets stored somewhere using it's stringValue. I'll update the question for the other requirements and reason why.

Comment: I see your problem. I edited my answer, but then realised I came up with pretty much the same code as in your original question